# Next.js page rendering glitch when refreshing pages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, httprequest

I'm having a weird problem that I originally just dismissed as a development glitch, but now I'm more concerned because It happens every time I refresh the page.
The issue is when I navigate to another page (localhost:3000/otherpage), *sometimes* it wont render that page at all. The page will turn completely white and have no HTML elements on the page (according to the dev tools inspector). However If I'm on that page and refresh this will ***always*** happen. Theses pages are dynamically rendered pages that have logic written that tells them to load a skeleton page while fetching the data, or render an error page if there's a problem with the request. I'm stumped as to why this is happening and have not been able to find anyone else that has experienced this problem yet.
My question is:
Why does this happen? and how can I work around this?

I have a screen recording to better explain whats going on.

(link to unlisted video):

https://youtu.be/mJPp3P4ElsI

Comment: It looks like the SSR fails to perform some part of a code. Have you used initiation of fetch inside of useEffect hook? As you know in NextJS the code of components first running on the Next server and after loading of the page - on a client side. Also you could try to use Node mode of DevTools to debug that issue - https://inspirnathan.com/_nuxt/img/img-1.e485730.png

Comment: I used getServerSideProps() to get the query parameter for the specific item i needed to fetch, then i used the useSWR hook to fetch the data. ex: `const apiEndpoint = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${props.id}`;`

Comment: Is there something that exists only on the client-side that could have an issue on a server?

Comment: I don't think so, the only thing I can think of is I'm using a Fastify backend and NextAuth. Maybe they don't like each other?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with `useSWR()`

Comment: UPDATE: it IS an issue with SWR, I removed it from the page and now there is no issue with refreshing. still not sure why but at least its fixed for the moment

Comment: Please provide a [mre].